# How do I encourage a robbery?

Tags: cook-serve-delicious

I want to stop a robbery so I can get the Steam achievement. I've been holding back on buying the security system upgrade just so I can do this, but I'm now on Day 101 with a five star restaurant, and have yet to be robbed once. I thought it might be a function of how much money you have on hand, so I let myself accrue over $10 000, but still, no dice. How can I encourage burglars to rob my establishment?!

Comment: yet another question that will look crazy when it hits the hot network questions.

Comment: For what it's worth, my original title was less crass :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way to increase the chance of getting robbed. The wiki states that a robber comes "at random".

> The ''chore'' starts after a robber at random runs through your restaurant, grabbing $400 from you. [Wiki](http://cookservedelicious.wikia.com/wiki/Robbery)
>
> By default, possibility of chores is determined by a percentage chance currently undisclosed by Vertigo Games.
>   Robberies are the least common chore for the player to encounter. [Another wiki](http://csd.wikia.com/wiki/Toilet#Work_Ticket_.28Clean.29)

There's a fixed percentage for a chore to happen and there is no known way how to increase the chances (Or at least not for a robbery)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and source - shame there isn't more publicly available info. I can't count how many dishes I've washed, toilets I've flushed, or trash I've taken out waiting for this. Oh well, I'll keep trying I guess!